# Convert data from opencv effectively

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm writing a program use both OpenCV and Kinect v2 SDK, where I met an awkward problem. I obtained vectors of Point2i（class consist of int X,Y) as indices of pixels, and I need to convert it into depthSpacePoint（a struct consisting of float32 X，Y）, which is simply depthSpacePoints.X = Point2i.X; or the other way around.

There are so many elements, writing a for loop would be too slow.

So I wonder if there any method like memcpy or other to do it faster?

Here is a brief of my code:

```
cv::findnonZeros(Mat A, vector<cv::Point2i> B);

vector<depthSpacePoint> C(B.size());

for(int i= 0; i < B.size(); ++i){
C[i].X = b[i].x;
C[i].Y = B[i].y;
}

icoordinateMapper(C.size(),C,...,...);
```

<- this is the reason why I convert it, because this library function only takes its own data type depthSpacePoint;

Comment: how do you obtain the points? maybe it's possible to get them as `Point2f`?

Comment: Maybe i can， I'm using findNonzeros(Mat, vector<Point2i>), using Point2f can be costing for memory, I guess it's a trade-off that I have to take.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own version of [`cv::findNonZero`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/e6d7989b203b7af02fe49f5c1ecdbcae41744568/modules/core/src/stat.cpp#L4038) that directly creates a `std::vector<depthSpacePoint>`.

It's just a matter of scanning ([efficiently](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html)) the matrix and checking a condition.

```
void findNonZeroSpacePoints( InputArray _src, std::vector<depthSpacePoint>& pts )
{
    // Get the src matrix, be sure it's of correct type
    Mat src = _src.getMat();
    CV_Assert( src.type() == CV_8UC1 );        

    // If src is all zero, return
    int n = countNonZero(src);
    if(n == 0) {
        pts.clear();
        return;
    }

    // Allocate pts
    pts.resize(n);        

    // Efficiently scan matrix and append points
    depthSpacePoint* ppts = pts.data();
    for( int i = 0; i < src.rows; i++ )
    {
        const uchar* bin_ptr = src.ptr(i);
        for( int j = 0; j < src.cols; j++ )
            if( bin_ptr[j] )
                *ppts ++ = depthSpacePoint(float(j), float(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this offers a new way to look at it. But according to my experience findNonZero() seems goes concurrent computation automatically, it might be difficult to beats its speed using single-thread loops.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Check the [implementation](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/e6d7989b203b7af02fe49f5c1ecdbcae41744568/modules/core/src/stat.cpp#L4038). Only `countNonZero` may use concurrent computation, but so it does in this function.

Comment: My mistake, it helps a lot, finds another way to speed things up